# Output from ycbcr2rgb has only ones and zeros

Tags: matlab, image-processing, jpeg

I'm trying to replicate the JPEG standard by encoding and decoding a sample image. It all looks right until the last decoding step where i should convert the reconstructed YCbCr image back to JPEG and plot it. However, applying `ycbcr2rgb` on the said array produces only ones and zeros, resulting in a pink image that resembles the original in some contours.

Comparing the initially transformed to YCbCr image (that is encoded) and the decoded YCbCr image (after applying the inverse steps) i can see that the values are similar with only marginal losses caused by the rounding of the quantized values in the encoding step. However, when applying the function to convert back to RGB colormap i get just ones and zeros. Have tried converting the reconstructed YCbCr image to uint8 or double before converting to RGB but to no avail. No difference in the final image.

What else can i do? It seems that `ycbcr2rgb` does not take additional arguments, so i can't see what else to try. Encoding and decoding functions attached below.

```
function [out, dict] = imageEncoder(image)
YCbCr = double(rgb2ycbcr(image));
encoded = zeros(size(YCbCr));

quantizationTable = [16 11 10 16 24 40 51 61 ;
     12 12 14 19 26 28 60 55 ;
     14 13 16 24 40 57 69 56 ;
     14 17 22 29 51 87 80 62 ;
     18 22 37 56 68 109 103 77 ;
     24 35 55 64 81 104 113 92 ;
     49 64 78 87 103 121 120 101;
     72 92 95 98 112 100 103 99];

for channel = 1:3
    for height = 1 : 8 : size(YCbCr, 1) - 7
        for width = 1 : 8 : size(YCbCr, 1) - 7
            % divide image in 8x8 blocks, for each channel individually
            pixelBlock = YCbCr(height : height + 7, width : width + 7, channel);
            % center pixel block values around zero by subtracting 128
            pixelBlock = pixelBlock - 128;
            % perform DCT type 2 for each block
            dctPixelBlock = dct2(pixelBlock);
            % block quantization
            quantizedBlock = round(dctPixelBlock./quantizationTable);
            encoded(height : height + 7, width : width + 7, channel) = quantizedBlock;
        end
    end
end

encoded2 = encoded(:);
symbols = transpose(unique(encoded2));
probabilities = histcounts(encoded2,length(symbols))/length(encoded2);
dict = huffmandict(symbols, probabilities);
out = huffmanenco(encoded2, dict);
end
```

Decoder, converting to uint8

```
function reconstructedImage = imageDecoder(encoded, dict)
decoded = huffmandeco(encoded, dict);
decoded = reshape(decoded, [128 128 3]);
reconstructedImage = zeros(size(decoded));

quantizationTable = [16 11 10 16 24 40 51 61 ;
    12 12 14 19 26 28 60 55 ;
    14 13 16 24 40 57 69 56 ;
    14 17 22 29 51 87 80 62 ;
    18 22 37 56 68 109 103 77 ;
    24 35 55 64 81 104 113 92 ;
    49 64 78 87 103 121 120 101;
    72 92 95 98 112 100 103 99];

for channel = 1:3
    for height = 1 : 8 : size(decoded, 1) - 7
        for width = 1 : 8 : size(decoded, 1) - 7
            dctValues = decoded(height : height + 7, width : width + 7, channel).*quantizationTable;
            iPixelBlock = idct2(dctValues);
            pixelBlock = iPixelBlock + 128;
            reconstructedImage(height : height + 7, width : width + 7, channel) = pixelBlock;
        end
    end
end

roundedImage = zeros(size(reconstructedImage));
roundedImage(:,:,1) = uint8(round(reconstructedImage(:,:,1)));
roundedImage(:,:,2) = uint8(round(reconstructedImage(:,:,2)));
roundedImage(:,:,3) = uint8(round(reconstructedImage(:,:,3)));
reconstructedImage = ycbcr2rgb(roundedImage);

end
```

Comment: Does `roundedImage` look as you expect?  I don't know if this is the problem but you're making `roundedImage` a double and then trying to fill it with unit8 values, perhaps if you make `roundedImage` a uint8 data type?

Comment: It looks fine and the values match with the original YCbCr (with some losses due to approximations). Also, it seems that `ycbcr2rgb` should work with double and integer types as well, so maybe that's not the problem.

Comment: Replace `reconstructedImage = ycbcr2rgb(roundedImage);` with `reconstructedImage = ycbcr2rgb(uint8(roundedImage));`. When you apply: `roundedImage(:,:,1) = uint8(round(reconstructedImage(:,:,1)));`, the class of roundedImage stays `double`.

Comment: Thanks @Rotem, that works. Mind adding it as an answer so i can flag it as the solution?

Comment: I am going to pass...
GrapefruitIsAwesome comment also solves the problem - you can make it uint8: `roundedImage = zeros(size(reconstructedImage), 'uint8');`.